# Questions on Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm now using the training set from OpenClassroom(http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=DeepLearning&doc=exercises/ex4/ex4.html) to give it a try on Logistic Regression, and I only use LR,unlike that page which uses LR and Newton's methods.
below is my code:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loadDataSet():
    dataMat = []; labelMat = []
    frX = open('../ex4x.dat')
    frY = open('../ex4y.dat')
    for line1 in frX.readlines():
        lineArr1 = line1.strip().split()
        dataMat.append([1.0, float(lineArr1[0]), float(lineArr1[1])])

    for line2 in frY.readlines():
        lineArr2 = line2.strip().split()
        labelMat.append(float(lineArr2[0]))
    return dataMat,labelMat

def sigmoid(inX):
    return 1.0/(1+exp(-inX))

# def autoNorm(dataSet):
# #   newValue = (oldValue-min)/(max-min)
#     minVals = min(dataSet)
#     maxVals = max(dataSet)
#     ranges = list(map(lambda x: x[0]-x[1], zip(maxVals, minVals)))
#     normDataSet = zeros(shape(dataSet))
#     m,n = shape(dataSet)
#     normDataSet = list(map(lambda x: x[0]-x[1], zip(dataSet,tile(minVals, (m,1)))))
#     normDataSet = normDataSet/tile(ranges, (m,1))
#     return normDataSet, ranges, minVals

def gradDescent(dataMatIn, classLabels):
    x = mat(dataMatIn)
    y = mat(classLabels).transpose()
    m,n = shape(x)
    alpha = 0.001
    maxCycles = 100000
    theta = ones((n,1))
    for k in range(maxCycles):
        h = sigmoid(x*theta)
        error = h - y
        cost = -1*dot(log(h).T,y)-dot((1-y).T,log(1-h))
        print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (k, cost))
        theta = theta - alpha * (x.transpose() * error /m)
    return theta

def plotBestFit(weights):
    dataMat,labelMat=loadDataSet()
    dataArr = array(dataMat)
    n = shape(dataArr)[0]
    xcord1 = []; ycord1 = []
    xcord2 = []; ycord2 = []
    for i in range(n):
        if int(labelMat[i])== 1:
            xcord1.append(dataArr[i,1]);ycord1.append(dataArr[i,2])
        else:
            xcord2.append(dataArr[i,1]);ycord2.append(dataArr[i,2])
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(xcord1, ycord1, s=30, c='red', marker='s')
    ax.scatter(xcord2, ycord2, s=30, c='green')
    min_x = min(mat(dataMat)[:, 1])
    max_x = max(mat(dataMat)[:, 1])
    x = arange(min_x, max_x, 1)
    y = (-weights[0]-weights[1]*x)/weights[2]
    ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlabel('X1'); plt.ylabel('X2');
    plt.show()

dataMat, classLabel = loadDataSet()
weights = gradDescent(dataMat, classLabel)
print weights
plotBestFit(weights.getA())
```

here is my questions:
1. I trained it for 100,000 times, with error was printed each iteration, I didn't see  it converaged anyway, well, actually I'm not sure here.
2. I'm not sure how to paint the classifier correctly by matplotlib, when the maxCycle is 200,000, I can get a somewhat reasonable classifier as well as the maxCyle is 100,000, the paint seems not reasonable at all.

[maxCycle is 100,000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4PDw.jpg)

UPDATE CODE:

```
count = 0
for i in range(80):
    result = sigmoid(dataMat[i] * weights)
    if result > 0.5:
        a = 1
    else:
        a = 0

    if float(a) != classLabel[i][0]:
        count += 1
errorRate = (float(count)/80)
print "error count is: %f, error rate is: %f" %(count,errorRate)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is actually fine! Here are some remarks:

1. You initialized the thetas with all ones. I would not do so in this example. The first call of the sigmoid function will return values close to `1`, because the product of `theta` and `x` gives very large numbers. The computation of `log(1 - h)` can result in error, because `log` is not defined at `0`. I prefer to initialize thetas with `0's`.
2. When calculating the cost function you missed the division by `m`. It does not matter for the algorithm, but it's better to follow the theory.
3. It's a good idea to plot the cost function, and not just print its values. The correct trend can be seen very clearly.
4. In order to converge, this particular example needs much more iterations. I reached a good result at `500.000` iterations.

**The post has been updated, see the UPDATE below**

Here are my plots:

[image: Cost function]

[image: Final separation border]

As you can see the resulting separation line matches the plot shown in your tutorial very well.

Here is my code. It differs a little bit from yours, but they are very similar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loadDataSet():
    dataMat = []; labelMat = []
    frX = open('../ex4x.dat')
    frY = open('../ex4y.dat')
    for line1 in frX.readlines():
        lineArr1 = line1.strip().split()
        dataMat.append([1.0, float(lineArr1[0]), float(lineArr1[1])])

    for line2 in frY.readlines():
        lineArr2 = line2.strip().split()
        labelMat.append([float(lineArr2[0])])
    return dataMat,labelMat

def sigmoid(inX):
    return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-inX))    

def gradDescent(dataMatIn, classLabels, alpha, maxCycles):
    x = np.mat(dataMatIn)
    y = np.mat(classLabels)
    m,n = np.shape(x)
    n = n - 1               #usually n is the number of features (without the 1's)

    theta = np.zeros((n+1,1))

    cost_history = []       #list to accumulate the cost values

    for k in range(maxCycles):

        h = sigmoid(x*theta)

        cost = ((-np.multiply(y, np.log(h)) -np.multiply(1-y, np.log(1-h))).sum(axis=0)/m)[0, 0]

        if ((k % 1000) == 0):
            cost_history.append(cost)   #on each 1000th iteration the cost is saved to a list

        grad = (x.transpose() * (h - y))/m

        theta = theta - alpha*grad

    plot_cost = 1 
    if (plot_cost == 1):
        plt.plot(cost_history)
        plt.title("Cost")
        plt.show()

    return theta   

def plotBestFit(dataMat, classLabel, weights):
    arrY = np.asarray(classLabel)
    arrX = np.asarray(dataMat)
    ind1 = np.where(arrY == 1)[0]
    ind0 = np.where(arrY == 0)[0]

    min_x1 = min(np.mat(dataMat)[:, 1])
    max_x1 = max(np.mat(dataMat)[:, 1])
    x1_val = np.arange(min_x1, max_x1, 1)
    x2_val = (-weights[0, 0]-weights[1, 0]*x1_val)/weights[2, 0]

    plt.scatter(arrX[ind1, 1], arrX[ind1, 2], s=30, c='red', marker='s')
    plt.scatter(arrX[ind0, 1], arrX[ind0, 2], s=30, c='blue', marker='s')
    plt.plot(x1_val, x2_val)
    plt.xlabel('X1', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('X2', fontsize=18)
    plt.title("Separation border")
    plt.show()


dataMat, classLabel = loadDataSet()
weights = gradDescent(dataMat, classLabel, 0.0014, 500000) 

print(weights)
plotBestFit(dataMat, classLabel, weights)
```

**UPDATE**

After reading your questions in the comments to the first edition of the post I tried to optimize the code to achieve the convergence of the cost function using much smaller number of iterations.

Indeed the feature standardization makes miracles :)

An even better result was achieved after only 30 iterations!

Here are the new plots:

[image]

[image]

Because of the standardization you need to scale each new test example, in order to classify it.

Here is the new code. I changed some data types to avoid unnecessary data type conversions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loadDataSet():
    dataMat = []; labelMat = []
    frX = open('../ex4x.dat')
    frY = open('../ex4y.dat')
    for line1 in frX.readlines():
        lineArr1 = line1.strip().split()
        dataMat.append([1.0, float(lineArr1[0]), float(lineArr1[1])])

    for line2 in frY.readlines():
        lineArr2 = line2.strip().split()
        labelMat.append([float(lineArr2[0])])

    return np.asarray(dataMat), np.asarray(labelMat)

def sigmoid(inX):
    return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-inX))    

def gradDescent(x, y, alpha, maxCycles):

    m,n = np.shape(x)
    n = n - 1               #usually n is the number of features (without the 1's)

    theta = np.zeros((n+1,1))

    cost_history = []       #list to accumulate the cost values
    cost_iter = []

    for k in range(maxCycles):

        h = sigmoid(np.dot(x, theta))

        cost = np.sum(-np.multiply(y, np.log(h)) -np.multiply(1-y, np.log(1-h)))/m


        cost_history.append(cost)   #on each 1000th iteration the cost is saved to a list
        cost_iter.append(k)

        grad = np.dot(x.transpose(), (h - y))/m

        theta = theta - alpha*grad

    plot_cost = 1 
    if (plot_cost == 1):
        plt.plot(cost_iter, cost_history)
        plt.title("Cost")
        plt.show()

    return theta   

def plotBestFit(arrX, arrY, weights):

    ind1 = np.where(arrY == 1)[0]
    ind0 = np.where(arrY == 0)[0]

    min_x1 = min(arrX[:, 1:2])
    max_x1 = max(arrX[:, 1:2])
    x1_val = np.arange(min_x1, max_x1, 0.1)
    x2_val = (-weights[0, 0]-weights[1, 0]*x1_val)/weights[2, 0]

    plt.scatter(arrX[ind1, 1], arrX[ind1, 2], s=30, c='red', marker='s')
    plt.scatter(arrX[ind0, 1], arrX[ind0, 2], s=30, c='blue', marker='s')
    plt.plot(x1_val, x2_val)
    plt.xlabel('X1', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('X2', fontsize=18)
    plt.title("Separation border")
    plt.show()


dataMat, classLabel = loadDataSet()
m = np.shape(dataMat)[0]

#standardization
dataMatMean = np.mean(dataMat, axis=0)
dataMatStd = np.std(dataMat, axis=0)

dataMatMean_m = np.tile(dataMatMean, (m, 1))
dataMatStd_m = np.tile(dataMatStd, (m, 1))

dataMatStand = np.copy(dataMat)
dataMatStand[:, 1:3] = np.divide(  (dataMatStand[:, 1:3] - dataMatMean_m[:, 1:3]),   dataMatStd_m[:, 1:3])

weights = gradDescent(dataMatStand, classLabel, 1.0, 30) 

print(weights)
plotBestFit(dataMatStand, classLabel, weights)
```

Comment: I did try it in Octave where I can reach a good result at 100 iterations, the only difference is that I used the built-in fminunc function instead.and is it reasonable or acceptable to reach a good result for 500.000 times for not using feature scaling?

Comment: I changed the learning rate to 0.001 and the iteration times to 500.000, then I got a result "error count is: 15.000000, error rate is: 0.187500", is this a good result or what I can do to improve the result? btw, the amount of training set is 80

Comment: @iamcodylee, I updated my post. I tried to scale the features and now you need only 30 iterations to get the result. Using 500.000 iterations is really a bad thing, but maybe it's a good example to get into the stuff and its optimization. Professional systems use much more efficient algorithms. I think nobody would use the pure gradient decent.

Comment: I'm just a novice on machine learning, so I wanna study it step by step, with feature scaling(I myself use normalization here, and it doesn't matter on what method I use to scale the feature), altho' it converges much faster than before, but I have no idea if you notice on the error count/error rate, the error count is from 15 up to 40 w/c means I get half right and half wrong result. I think this is not a good result. what can I do to improve the result?

Comment: I think I did not get the question. Could you describe the mentioned issue about error count/erro rate on an example? Or maybe you can edit your question and add some new notes and examples?

Comment: I simply put the weights calculated from training set back into the training set to validate the accuracy and the threshold is 0.5(well,actually here I should use another sample training set to validate my result, w/c called cross validation),I updated the code above.
now the code with normalization got a wrong count of 40(total samples count is 80). the code w/o normalization got a wrong count of 15. thus I think this is not a good result,and my question is what to do to improve my code? Do I express myself clearly?

Comment: In order to use the weights gained from the normalized version you need to normalize your inputs before using the classification. As can be seen from my second picture the wrong count is 15 as well.